# Етимологія слова "бузько"?

Tags: етимологія, іменники

Знаємо, що одним із синонімів до слова лелека є **бузько, бузьок** (діал.). А яка етимологія цього слова? В [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) цього слова немає.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Це слово пішло від польського ["buzia"](https://uk.glosbe.com/pl/uk/buzia) (редуплікативне утворення), що має багато позитивних значень: обличчя, губи, рот, донечка, статуетка, лялечка тощо. Оскільки лелеки були вісниками щастя, то їм і надали таку ніжну й пестливу назву. Слово бузя наявне і в українській мові: [Словник Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/3655-buzja.html) та [ЕСУМ](http://resource.history.org.ua/cgi-bin/eiu/history.exe?&I21DBN=ELIB&P21DBN=ELIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=elib_all&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=ID=&S21COLORTERMS=0&S21STR=0007834):

[image: бузя]